# Convert string type number to sfixed in synthesizable vhdl

Tags: string, casting, type-conversion, vhdl, fixed

I have a string containing a number for example 3.76, I want to convert this parsed string to an `sfixed` value in vhdl. The trick I was using is to transform string to real using real'image(string) and then calling `to_fixed(value, integer part, -precision)`. But this approach is not synthesizable(real'image). I want to know if there is another way such as transforming a string to std_logic_vector and then casting to sfixed using `To_slv()`. What are the steps to transform a string for example 3.76 to `sfixed` notation in synthesizable vhdl?

Comment: Where does the string come from? File? ROM? other IO? How do you imagine the parsing being done in hardware? Maybe you should explain more about your application and your setting..

Comment: The string comes from an input file. This file contains strings in this format 3.344 1.456 4.452 for example. These values are loaded to sfixed variables at initialization.

Comment: so you have a file and you want synthesize code that coverts the information in the file to a signal. How do you image the FPGA doing file IO? How will the file reach the FPGA at all? you connect a HDD to the FPGA?

Comment: The values are loaded at initialization, so they are loaded before being downloaded to FPGA.

Comment: What reads the files at initialisation then? You should really elaborate in your question and give some coding examples, because it is just not clear what you want.

Comment: How about processing the file offline (using Python/PERL/awk/sed/a texteditor/MS Excel/whatever) into a more suitable format? (eg VHDL that can be pasted into you source code)

Comment: Have you already read the FPHDL documentation about `sfixed` on GitHub: https://github.com/FPHDL/fphdl ? I'm very sure David also provides conversion functions for type string. Edit: search for: `from_string`

Answer (score 0):

The [FPHDL](https://github.com/FPHDL/fphdl) library, with offers e.g. the type `sfixed`, provides a conversion function `from_string`. You can find more information in the file `fixed_ug.pdf`.

These examples are from the documentation:

```
  signal a : ufixed (3 downto –3);
begin
  a <= from_string (“0000.000”, a’high, a’low);
  a <= from_string (“0001.000”, a);
  a <= from_string (“0000.100”); -- Works only if size is exact
```

Comment: Yes, but this is not from an input file, nor is it in the "3.76" format. So it doesn't answer his question.

Comment: His primary question is about transforming a `string` input to an `sfixed`. His secondary question goes into the direction of file I/O. He also showed that his first attempt of using `real'image(...)` doesn't work, so one can assume he already implemented file reading.

Comment: Maybe, but he should elaborate on that. Show more code examples, etc. He should at least show the code that cannot be synthesized.